# Expectation infinite sums of random variables and the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

My question consists of two subparts. I hope anyone can help me out.

a) Consider a sequence of random variables $X_n$ defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and define $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ for $n\geq 1$. Let $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n =S$.

Assume all $X_n \geq 0 $. Show that $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}(X_k)$ using the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

b) Drop the assumption that $X_n$ is non-negative. Show $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|X_k|)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}(|X_k|)$

My attempt to answer part a):

Since $X_n \geq0$, we have that $0\leq S_1\leq S_2 \leq \cdots \text{ a.s.}$
Then according to the Monotone Convergence Theorem we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}(S_n)=\mathbb{E}(S)$. So now we get that:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}(S_n)=\mathbb{E}(S) =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}(X_k) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(X_k) $$

I'm not quite sure whether this answer for question a) is correct.

For part b) my idea is as follows:

I would define $|X_k|=X^{+}_k +X^{-}_k$, where $X^{+}_k = \max(0,X_k)$ and $X^{-}_k =\max(-X_k,0)$. I would also define $S^{+}_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X^{+}_k$ and $S^{-}_n =\sum_{k=1}^n X^{-}_k$. Then I would use a similar strategy as in question a) but for $S^{+}_{n}$ and $S^{-}_n$ in this case.

Comment: I must be missing something, but if in part b you let $Y_i = | X_i |$, and then apply part (a) to the set of all $Y$s, aren't you done?

Comment: @JohnHughes Ah, I see! That's actually easier to do, indeed.

Comment: "Then according to the Monotone Convergence Theorem we have that $\lim E(S_n) = E(S)$". At this point, the name $S$ is undefined. I think you need to define it before talking about its expectation.

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks for pointing this out. I edited it. $S$ is the limit of $S_n$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: And how to you know that this limit exists (when you're stating the problem)? [To be honest: I personally know it does *not* exist. Picking $\Omega = \{0, 1\}$, uniform probability, counting measure, and $X_i(s) = s$ for all $i$, the limit $S$ is infinite for all points of the probability space, hence $S$ is not a random variable on your probability space. ]